# I need to convert the quarter and year into numeric form in r apparently so the program can understand it

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3An8.png)

Apparently im supposed to convert the quarters and year into numeric form so that r can understand it but I am confused on how to do that... It's also not just for the time frame in the picture but from Q1 1990 to Q2 2020. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `as.yearqtr` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
as.numeric(as.yearqtr(str1, "Q%q %Y"))
[1] 1990.00 2020.25
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Q1 1990", "Q2 2020")
```